# Create a table in current user schema in HANA stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, ddl, hana, hana-sql-script

I have some stored procedures that create tables that we use for validation purposes. Most of these tables get dropped on the procedure next execution.

I created these procedures and when I run them they run fine, but my problem is that now we want someone else to run those procedures, but they can't.

After some research, I found out that problem was that the stored procedure is trying to write into my schema, so since the users didn't have access to my scheme, they would get that insufficient privileges error.

Is there any way that the stored procedure would create tables into the scheme from where the stored procedure was called from rather than the schema belonging to whomever created the stored procedure?

Here is a small stored procedure I created for testing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXX.SP_TMP_TEST ()
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
SQL SECURITY INVOKER  AS
BEGIN
    CALL XXX.SP_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS ('TMP_TEST');
    CREATE COLUMN TABLE TMP_TEST (TEST INTEGER);
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON XXX.SP_TMP_TEST TO USER_B;
```

Let's say USER_A creates this stored procedure in Schema XXX

Now every time USER_A calls it, table TMP_TEST gets created into USER_A schema.

Let's say USER_B tries to run it. They would get an error saying two tables with the same name can not exist. This is because the stored procedure to drop the table drops the table from USER_B's schema, but the create table tries to create the table on USER_A's schema.

The only way for this to work is to change SQL_SECURY TO DEFINER, but that would let USER_B create tables into USER_A's schema, and I want the tables to be created into USER_B's schema or USER_C or D, whoever calls the stored procedure.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

This HANA SQLScript behavior is indeed not as documented.

The documentation tells us that if a procedure does not specify the `DEFAULT SCHEMA` then the **current_schema** of the session is used for unqualified objects (that is, objects where the schema name is not mentioned in the command).

If we rely on this (at least up until HANA 2 SP 04) then we run into the situation the OP described: instead of the **current_schema** of the session, the schema that the procedure is "in" gets used for unqualified objects.

Personally, I would guess that this is a documentation error.

How to handle the requirement (single procedure that is callable from other users) now?

One way can be to use dynamic SQL for this scenario.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_in_my_schema()

   SQL SECURITY INVOKER 

AS
BEGIN
    
    IF (obj_exists (CURRENT_USER, 'TAB_X') = 1) THEN 
        EXEC 'DROP TABLE "'|| current_user ||'"."TAB_X"';
    END IF;
     
    EXEC 'CREATE TABLE "'|| current_user ||'"."TAB_X" (USERNAME NVARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY)';
   
END;
```

The `OBJ_EXISTS` function is a custom function that checks whether or not an object exists (see https://www.lbreddemann.org/if-exists-would-exist/ for the definition).

The main "trick" is to use the `CURRENT_USER` function to specify the target schema name for the desired actions.
These are then executed in dynamic SQL `EXEC` commands;

All this has nothing to do with the `SECURITY AS DEFINER` setting. This rather specifies the security context (who **owns** the created tables) and not which **namespace** (schema) the tables belong to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately using dynamic SQL for what I need won’t be an option. We have over a hundred procedures and each one has at least 5 queries that need to crear tables, so along with taking too long to change very thing, it would make it harder to debug. I have used dynamic sql in other Stored procedures and it works great, but for this I am hoping there is another solution.

Comment: This requirements sounds a lot like it would be best implemented in a language where the schema can effectively separated from DB objects. With SQL/SQLScript this is not the case. SInce `CREATE TABLE` does not respect the current schema of the session, I would look to implement the creation of the DB objects to DB-client code. The question is of course also: why does every user have to have tables created in their schema? One main usage scenario of SQL DBs is to have a **shared** DB (=one set of tables) that is used by many.